Previous & Next buttons on the survey are a page ahead
On the 2024 Survey results the Previous & Next buttons assume you're already on the next page.
The order of pages is Developer Profile, Technology, AI, Work, Community, Professional Developers, and Methodology. If you're on the Community page, the Previous button goes to Community, and the Next button goes to Methodology. This bug exists across all pages.

